# Swift 3 Core Data - NSExpression combine multiple functions

Tags: core-data, swift3, nsexpression

I need this expression
--> sum:(abs:(amount) * -1)

and my code is:

```
let absExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "abs:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: Table.COLUMN_AMOUNT)])
let minusAbsExpression = NSExpression(format: "%@ * -1", argumentArray: [absExpression])
let trueExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [minusAbsExpression])
```

but crash with down reason:

```
reason: 'Unsupported function expression sum:(abs:(amount) * -1)'
```

Comment: Where it is crashing in the third line or in any other code which is not here?

Comment: In line 3 @ViniApp